# Posting HTML form using jQuery and/or AJAX

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am/have been utterly confused for several days now and cannot get my form to submit to a server. I've attempted every guide, tutorial, example and forum suggestion the internet offers and still no avail.

We can post this form to a variable number of different servers and this is done through a select/option drop down using 'id' as the variable. We use a button to submit the form and receive an XML in response which we need to see in an XML format. This XML response needs to be directed to display in an iframe within a different frameset. Below is a tid-bit of the code.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="jQuery-1.12.4.js">
    $("#Form51").submit(function (e) {
        var url = "https://website.com:1234"; 

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: $("#Form51"), 
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data); 
            }
        });

    });

</script>
</head>
<body> 

<form method="POST" name="form51" target="formresponse" id="form51">

<button>Submit</button>


....data
..data
data
</form>
</body>
```

Thanks if anyone can assist in resolving with me my headache on this :/

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Have you tried adding an 'error:' in your ajax config to see the response (if any)?

Comment: are you trying to use the select element as the ajax url? if so, you aren't getting the information correctly into the url var.

Comment: Where is the implementation for postservername() ? Could you share this!

Comment: @Ju66ernaut, no errors are coming up. I've had 'error' in the ajax you see above but nothing ever pops up.

Comment: @Cruiser I tried hard coding the url in the ajax and it still didn't submit. It was formed like this - "https://cert1.tpayment.com:7969".  The part about the postservername() is just a display and can be ignored

Comment: @GHKarim The part about the postservername() is just a display and can be ignored

Comment: have you tried adding e.preventDefault(); into the submit function?

Comment: @Cruiser , using the code above, where should that go then

Comment: @HygSuperSlayer I am not sure of Cruiser's suggestion! but unless I am mistaken, this should go first line in your submit function!

Comment: I added an answer for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the form is trying to submit without running the code in your js. It's defaulting to the submit action, which isn't what you want. Try adding e.preventDefault() right after your event handler:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="jQuery-1.12.4.js">
$("#Form51").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //<-----------------------------------try this here
    var url = "https://website.com:1234"; 

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $("#Form51"), 
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data); 
        }
    });

});

</script>
</head>
<body> 

<form method="POST" name="form51" target="formresponse" id="form51">

<button>Submit</button>


....data
...data
data
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Beautiful! Working now!

Comment: I'm happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are submitting your data to a variable number of servers, each with different URLs, you may be running into problems with [Cross-Origin Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) Sharing ([CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)). You may need to make some changes to your web server to indicate to browsers that those other domains are valid and trusted before they will submit to and display responses from another domain.

You will need to tweak your web server to insert some additional HTTP headers. Eg:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://foo.com
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, DELETE
```

On [apache](http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html) this is done by adding to one of the config files:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://foo.com"
```

Comment: the form is being sent to only one of the possible servers. We can post to the server using a plain old javascript.  `      function HandlePostBack(form) {
            form.action = document.getElementById("TRXNSrvr").value;
            d = document.getElementById("TRXNSrvr").value;
            if (d == 0) {
                alert("Please select a server to process this transaction!");
            }
            else { 
                form.submit();
            }
        }`

Comment: It won't matter which one you send it to, the servers all have different domains from the web page that you are submitting from and the browser will block this to prevent a cross-site-scripting attack unless you authorize the domains. This usually register's in chrome's debug console (F12, click "Console" - you will see "Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP. ")

Comment: I'll keep that in mind since the other two servers are not yet configured to accept form submissions. We are only using the cert1 server and it works fine using javascript to post.

Comment: So i completely take out the select/option code and hardcode the cert1 server name in for the url and it still will not post to the server